# How to use graphic in Windows Phone 8.1?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

In WinForm, I use graphic like this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Graphics g;
    int r = 80; int c = 80; int dd = 20; int[,] arr; int d = 10; int flag;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        arr = new int[r, c];
        SetArr(arr, r, c);
    }

    private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        g = this.CreateGraphics();

        for (int i = 0; i <= r; i++)
            g.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Blue, 1), 0, i * dd, r * dd, i * dd);

        for (int j = 0; j <= c; j++)
            g.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Blue, 1), j * dd, 0, j * dd, c * dd);
    }
    ...
}
```

Can anyone show me how to draw those same line in Windows Phone?

Comment: Have you looked at how to draw with XAML?

Comment: BTW, you should not call `CreateGraphics()`.

Comment: I want to draw in C# code @RowlandShaw

Comment: You can still draw by adding XAML elements from the code behind, if you *really want to*

Comment: The other alternate would be to go down the XNA route

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `<Grid x:Name="grid" />` to your XAML code and then either add lines using XAML:

```
<Line Stroke="Blue" StrokeThickness="1" X1="1" X2="2" Y1="16" Y2="18" />
```

or via code:

```
Line line = new Line();
line.Stroke = Colors.Blue;
line.StrokeThickness = 1;
line.X1 = 1; 
line.X2 = 2;
line.Y1 = 16;
line.Y2 = 18;
grid.Children.Add(line);
```